# Write a Java method changeBlue(weight)

Tags: java

Write a method `changeBlue(weight)`. Do not change any color of the pixels in the first half of the picture. For the second half, change blue value of each pixel by `new blue=original blue * weight`.

> For example, if a pixel has values (200,100,100) and weight is 0.5,
>   then the new values will be (200,100,50). If the weight is 1.5, then
>   the new values will be (200,100,150).

You can use any image to test this method.

Here's what I have.  I think I'm pretty close, but I'm getting some errors.  Any advice is appreciated.

```
public void changeBlue(int weight)
{
    Pixel[] pixelArray = this.getPixels();
    Pixel pixelObj = null;
    int value = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while (index >= pixelArray.length/2)
    {

        pixelObj = pixelArray[index];

        value = pixelObj.getBlue();

        value = (value * weight);

        pixelObj.setBlue(value);

        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: `index >= pixelArray.length/2`, my best guess is that this `loop` wont execute pretty often.

Comment: Following the comment of @KevinEsche you should loop through all the array using a `for` loop and inside check if it's the right half with an `if` statement, or maybe just start the index at the second half of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, the parameter of the `changeBlue`method is an `int`, shouldn't this be a `double` given your specification?

You also have `index` initially set to `0`, and your loop only runs whilst `index` >= half the pixel array length (`pixels.length / 2`). So this loop won't ever start unless `pixels.length / 2` returns `0`. Once it has started, it'll also never terminate.

You would be best to use a `for` statement. Initialise an `int` to half the array length (`pixels.length / 2`), set it to terminate after the loop executes the last `pixels` array index (`pixels.length - 1`), and make sure it increments by `1` each time.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html for details and how to use a `for` statement.

Additionally, if `setBlue()` takes an `int` as a parameter, you should cast it. e.g. `(int) (weight * value)`. But you do not provide any details of the `Pixel` class.

Example implementation:

```
public void changeBlue(double weight) {
    for (int i = pixelArray.length / 2; i < pixelArray.length; i++) {
        pixelArray[i].setBlue((int) (pixelArray[i].getBlue() * weight));
    }
}
```

On a practical note, if blue becomes 0 you won't be able to change it using `changeBlue`, but this behaviour would be somewhat logical in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I was just thinking about weight needing to be double.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best implementation but try :

```
public void changeBlue(int weight)
{
     Pixel[] pixelArray = this.getPixels();
     Pixel pixelObj = null;
     int value = 0;
     int index = 0;
     int halfSize = pixelArray.length/2; 

     for (index = 0; index <= pixelArray.length; index++) {
         if (index <= halfSize){
             // FIrts half of the file 
         }
         if (index > halfSize) {
             // Seconde part of the file 
             pixelObj = pixelArray[index];

             value = pixelObj.getBlue();
             value = (value * weight);

             pixelObj.setBlue(value);
         }
     }
}
```